# Reference request: finding a biophysics paper about super time resolution imaging of a neuron firing

Tags: specific-reference, biophysics

About a year ago I attended a talk at the University of Ottawa. The author described a method for achieving super time resolution images of a neuron firing. From what I can recall, the group found a small protein that acted as a photovoltaic cell (produced a voltage pulse in response to a photon) and engineered it to run in reverse, emitting a photon when it was subjected to a voltage pulse. They then cause this to be expressed in neurons, and were able to image action potentials moving through the network, heralded by emitted light from these proteins. Super resolution was achieved by careful timing and a lot of averaging.

I have looked high and low for this paper for about a week now, with no luck. I don't remember the speaker's name (though he was a pretty young guy, a new prof at the time if I recall). If anyone is familiar with the research and can link me to the paper I would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you tried looking through [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed)?

Comment: I have been trying since shortly after you commented, but so far no luck!

Comment: Isn't this the one : [Superresolution Imaging of Chemical Synapses in the Brain](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627310009372)?

Comment: While that paper looks very interesting, it's not the one. That group achieves super-resolution imaging in space; the one I am looking for does super-resolution in the time domain to actually make videos of action potentials moving along a neuron.

Comment: Ah, was too quick. Google Scholar? UO schedule to get the name of the guy?